# Using JQuery with HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

It's been a while since I've done web programming and I'm trying to start again. However, I cannot seem to get JQuery to work.

In my javascript file I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#canvas').mousedown(function(e){
      alert("I am an alert box!");
    });
});
```

However, nothing happens when I click the canvas.

I know everything is linked properly because at the top of my javascript file I have this:

```
function loader()
{
var canvas = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.5)";
canvas.fillRect(225, 105, 200, 200);
}
```

(In the HTML file I have `<body onload="loader()">`)

And that works fine and displays a pink box when I load the page.

Anyone know why this may be happening? Thanks.

Comment: [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/2BuZ5/). Are you sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/ZurbR/

Comment: Uh oh. Now I have no idea what's going on......... lol

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: It has to be loaded if the loader function is working, right?

Comment: @RyanPeschel check the DOM tree in dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

The problem was that I linked my javascript file before the jQuery file.

Basically, switched these two lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i don't see how that solves it. if your `.ready` call is in `canvas.js`, that would fail since jQuery isn't loaded yet.